# mysqli_num_rows not returning accurate results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that is supposed to take a form email value and query the database for duplicates. However, regardless of if I use an existing email (in the database) or a new one, I get "success".

My script looks like this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['email'])) {

    $email = $_POST['email'];

    // query the database for duplicates
    $query = 'SELECT email FROM user_info WHERE email = "$email"';
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
        echo "Email already taken";
    } else {
        echo "Success";
    }
```

Obviously `mysqli_num_rows` is returning *some* kind of data - or none at all.

Does anyone understand why I would not get a returned row if I'm selecting an email that already exists in the database?

**EDIT**

```
    $('#email').blur( function() {
    if(!this.value){
        $('#jquery_msg').html("Email can't be empty");
    } else if (!filter.test(this.value)){
        $('#jquery_msg').html("Not a valid email");
    } else {
        var emailVal = $('#email').val();
        // make an ajax call
        $.ajax({
            url: 'validation.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {'email': 'emailVal'},
            success: function(data, status) {
                $('#jquery_msg').html(data);
                //  console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
            }
        }); // end ajax call
    }
});
```

The problem is in the data that's being passed to the PHP script via Ajax.  What I thought was the value of `$('#email').val();` was literally `emailVal`.  Huh..
Now I need to solve how to pass the value into the Ajax call properly.

Thank you all for you help.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). `$_POST` data **NEVER** goes directly into the query.

Comment: You should not change your question based on the answers you get as they will stop making sense.

Comment: 'Single quotes' block variable expansion, so you are checking that there is no email equal to "dollar+e+m+a+i+l". Of course there won't be. At the very least you need "SELECT... WHERE email='{$email}'" (notice the quote signs). And *also* you want to use bound parameters, so: `'SELECT... WHERE email=?'`;

Answer (score 4):

This is wrong:

```
$query = 'SELECT email FROM user_info WHERE email = "$email"';
```

Apart from the potential sql injection problem, variables do not get parsed when you use single quotes.

You should use a prepared statement instead:

```
$query = 'SELECT email FROM user_info WHERE email = ?';
```

Then you can prepare the statement, bind the placeholder and get the results. Check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) for more information.

A quick solution would also be:

```
$query = 'SELECT email FROM user_info WHERE email = "'
            . mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $email) . '"';
```

**Edit:** To trouble-shoot further problems, you should add error handling to your database calls. You can have mysqli throw exceptions telling you exactly what is wrong - if anything - by adding this to the top of your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Comment: I appreciate the security risks but right now I'm just trying to get a basic working script.  Any ideas why I would not be getting a returned row if inputting a duplicate email into the select statement?

Comment: @David Check my edit. If you still have problems, post your actual code below the original version and add the exact error messages.

Comment: Thanks for your help Jeroen. I added the code in your edit but I'm not getting any errors hah

Comment: @David All 3 lines and the original answer? If so, check your values, perhaps you have spaces or something similar before or after your e-mail address in the database or the variable. Adding your actual code would also help.